# Change a single variable with less.js

Tags: javascript, css, less

I am trying to use less.js to make modifications to a less stylesheet for demonstration purposes.  What I would like it to do is remember previous changes so I only have to send a single change each time for efficiency.  Let's say I have the following:

```
@PrimaryColor: #FFF;
@SecondaryColor: #000;
```

If I change one parameter, it works fine.

```
less.modifyVars({ "@PrimaryColor": "#ff0000" });
```

The colors now look like this:

```
@PrimaryColor: #ff0000;
@SecondaryColor: #000;
```

Now if I call the method again:

```
less.modifyVars({ "@SecondaryColor": "#00ff00" });
```

The primary color switches back and the secondary color changes:

```
@PrimaryColor: #FFF;
@SecondaryColor: #00ff00;
```

My question is whether there is a way or a method that will just change the one parameter and leave the other changes alone?

Comment: which version of less do you use?

Comment: I am using version 1.4.2

Comment: Why not just add the second change to the first and pass `{"@PrimaryColor":"#FF0000", "@SecondaryColor":"#00FF00"}` as a parameter?

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing to get around the issue.  I was mostly curious if this was something that could be done on a single variable basis.  Would it provide any performance benefits or is changing 30 or 40 parameters at a time efficient enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.4.2.js) of modifyVars seems to confirm that you can't do it.

It looks like the source `.less` file is recompiled every time you call `modifyVars` and only those changes that you passed in the last `modifyVars` call are applied.