# Get every value from a box-shadow by regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, css

I'm looking for suggestions for a problem I'm having right now. I want to be able to change programatically the values of a box-shadow ie: `box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;`.

And my issue is worst, I need it to be at least 2 properties together.

Example output of chrome:
`box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 5px 10px, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 4px 10px inset;`

So my issue is

1. how can I first separate the two styles, just `.split(",")` wont cut it because it creates an array because of rgb(,,)
2. If I get to split it, how to take care in case of HEX, rgb, or rgba, would a regex suffice?

Edit: I have to be able to make this splits in the browser, that's why I'm looiking for a js solution

Thank you.

---

Solution

Using @BYossarian answer I've added the following to continue the split the different box-shadow values

`string.split(/,(?![^(]*))/);`

and the following to split the white spaces

`string.split(/ (?![^(]*))/);`

outputting

["rgb(0, 0, 0)", "0px", "5px", "12px", "0px"]

The rest is just finding strings

var box_shadow_properties = box_shadow.split(/ (?![^(]*))/);

ie: getting the h-shadow v-shadow blur spread properties if(box_shadow_properties[i].indexOf("px") !== -1)

ie: getting the color property
if (box_shadow_properties[i].indexOf("rgb") !== -1 || box_shadow_properties[i].indexOf("#") !== -1)

Hope someone finds this helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of splitting the string, the only commas should either be within brackets as part of a colour value, or separating the various box-shadow values. Since you want to split along the latter, you need to look for commas which aren't followed by an unopened closing bracket. i.e. commas that aren't followed by a ')' without a '(' inbetween the comma and the ')'.
You can do that using the regex:

```
/,(?![^\(]*\))/
```

So that you'd use:

string.split(/,(?![^(]*))/);

Then in terms of identifying the colour values, you might want to start by looking at:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/

Comment: I think your answer is in the right path but the code isn't workin
`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /,(?![^(]*))/: Unmatched ')'`

Comment: @FrancisReynolds it works ok for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Xg269/  Are you sure you copied it correctly, and that there aren't any other unmatched ')'s in your code?

Comment: the `string.split()` part had two characters less! (`the \ before ) `) that was it! it works how it should! Thx

Comment: @BenJackson You can use `^(` instead of `^\(`. No need for escaping inside `[]`

Comment: The second regex should be =>  `/ (?![^(]*\))/`. Otherwise babel throws an SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

Not a regex-based-solution, but worth knowing:

using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) you can bind each shadow value to a variable, like this:

```
@a: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 5px 10px;
@b: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 4px 10px inset;

some_element {
   box-shadow: @a, @b; 
}
```

and then modify them at runtime with javascript using LESS built-in function `modifyVars()`:

```
less.modifyVars({
   '@a': 'rgb(0, 0, 255) 6px 5px 20px'
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the idea is to edit it inside the browser, I'm going to edit my post right now.

Comment: this works inside browser. The only limitations I can think of are: 1. you can only set _new values_, the current ones cannot be read this way; 2. [variables are reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485685/change-a-single-variable-with-less-js/19500647#19500647) after every change.